# jQuery/Javascript - How to subtract old scrolltop from new scrolltop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I've got a seamingly simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out. Every time a user scrolls the scrollTop changes. I want to subtract the old from the new value of the scrollTop. But how do i store the old value, so i can subtract it from the new value after the user stops scrolling? There must be an easy way.

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      var curTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var newTop = (curTop - curTop);
      console.log(newTop);  
   });
});
```

This obviously doesn't work. You guys have any idea?

Comment: You probably don't want to call that function **every** time the scroll event is fired. I believe it will fire for every tiny increment/decrement in your position.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: [if (oldTop-curTop==0) {alert('stoppped scrolling');} ?](http://jsfiddle.net/xCpH4/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Define oldScrollTop outside of the scope of the function, in the global scope and update it every time the function is call, after the computation you make with the data.

This way, the "old" value will remain stored from one function call to the other in the global scope. By global scope, I mean outside of any function call, even outside of jquery's document.ready

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$(function(){
  var curTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      var newTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var diff = newTop - curTop;
      curTop = newTop;
      console.log(diff);
   });
});
```

it stores the current scrollTop in `curTop` and updates it on every scroll event after the difference of the old and the new scrolltop is calculated.